# Using React Router to get files

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to read a text file into a variable.

I used a fetch instruction with the url of the file and it didn't work because my nginx web server was configured to pass all queries to React.

And React doesn't serve static files, or maybe I need to define some routes.

I solved the problem hacking the nginx configuration, but I'm told that it's too much hacking and I have to use React routing or something else.

So, imagine I have a file whose url is http://www.example.com/rankitapp/src/T9tutorial/dictionary.txt

If I write a fetch:

```
fetch("/rankitapp/src/T9tutorial/dictionary.txt")
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then(function(data) {

        t9init(data);

     })
```

It works only if I hack nginx configuration.

With the original, standard configuration where nginx passes all queries to React, it doesn't work.

Knowing that I can't hack nginx, how do I fetch that file?

Do I create some special route?

Do I somehow import the file in a variable using any other instruction?

Answer (score 0):

We use Axios instead of fetch, it does things for you like handling HTTP status errors much better. Our setup is that we load enviromental variables into redux through a JSON file.

This sounds like it could be part of the problem:

```
.then(response => response.text())
```

Which "converts the response to text" before you can use it.

Our code looks like:

```
const request = {
    url: 'http://example.com/my/file.text',
    method: 'GET'
};

return axios(request)
.then((response) => {
  // response.data has our data / values
  // we take the raw JSON and shove this into our redux state.
  // No parsing or anything like that. 
  // No need to run response.text() on it
})
.catch((error) => {
  dispatch(failureHandler(error));
});
```

This is worth reading for [Axios vs Fetch](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5)

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using Axios.

In my case the url http://example.com/my/file.text would be processed by React because Nginx passes all http queries to React.

React doesn't know how to serve back a text file, in this case file.txt.

I have been told that I shouldn't tamper with Nginx configuration and I should know better how to use React routing.

I suppose that in your case there is something in your Nginx or Apache configuration that makes the web server serve files like file.txt ignoring that React even exists.

Or maybe something else.

Comment: The .then(response => response.text()) part is OK because the file is text, not JSON.